# How to import a project with modules and java packages in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

We have a java project with several modules. We use git for versioning and want the developers to be able to chose their own IDE. So we don't push .idea and .iml files with git. This means that developers in IntelliJ needs who clones from git needs to set up the project in IntelliJ as well. However we are having some issues with setting it up. In my own project it works fine and looks like:

```
Proejct Module (Is this a real module?)
   ⤷ Module A
        ⤷ src
           ⤷ main
               ⤷ java
                   ⤷ Package 1
                   ⤷ Package 2
           ⤷ test
   ⤷ Module B
```

Before we added packages to the project new developers could just pull from git and open *Module P* in IntelliJ, then go to project structure and import module from *Module A* and *Module B*. However if they try the same thing now IntelliJ tries to make the Modules *main* and *test* from *Module A*.

A workaround we temporarily use for this is to open Module A and B directly as separate IntelliJ projects. If we do this IntelliJ does not try to make modules out of *main* and *test*. However this is very inconveniant for us.

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good approach to make your source control system "agnostic" about the IDE and not check in `.idea`, `*.iml` and equivalent things from other IDE's.

However you really need to use a build control system like `maven` or `gradle`.

In my workplace we use maven for all our java projects. It's very simple to define a `pom.xml` at the root level which defines your modules, and many other things.

When you import a maven project into intellij, all the relevant IntelliJ modules are *automatically* created for you. In essence, you only need to import the `pom.xml` and you're good to go.

Otherwise it will be a nightmare to import and create modules every time you check out source from git. Maven isn't perfect but I highly recommend using either maven or gradle.

To define multi-modules from the root `pom.xml`, make a section like this:

```
<modules>
    <module>module-A</module>
    <module>module-B</module>
</modules>
```

And then the `pom.xml` in both module A and B should define a section referring to the root pom via the `<parent>` tag.

Comment: We are in fact using maven however each module has it's own pom. From what you write it sounds like we can sort this out by defining the modules in a pom at the top level?

Comment: exactly, I added to my answer. Referring to the parent pom from the sub module is important. Once you can control-click into the modules and then back to the parent, everything is configured correctly.